# Installing mbed TLS with libmbedtls-dev

Tags: mbedtls

I am currently working with mbed TLS and I discovered something odd:

I want to extract the CRT parameters of a private RSA key with the mbedtls_rsa_export_crt() function [1]. Unfortunately the function is missing. The problem seems to be that I have installed the libraries over the package manager. Concrete I have installed the libmbedtls-dev package [2].

Is the code in [2] deprecated or why are some functions missing?

[1] https://tls.mbed.org/api/rsa_8h.html

[2] https://packages.debian.org/de/sid/libmbedtls-dev

Thank you for your support

MK14

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. The problem was that I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my mashine and the Xenial Repo contains an old version of the mbedtls package. Installing the [mbedtls package from the Bionic repo](https://medium.com/@george.shuklin/how-to-install-packages-from-a-newer-distribution-without-installing-unwanted-6584fa93208f) solved my issue.

Regards
ckmk14